# merge multiple worksheets into a new sheet with condition

Tags: excel, merge

I have two sheets I want to merge into a new sheet such that: the new sheet is the same **Sheet 2** with multiple columns from **Sheet 1**.

**Sheet 1**:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Colm 4 | Colm 5 | Colm 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 20 | x | xx |
| a | 1 | 2 | 1 | z | r |
| a | 1 | 3 | 22 | h | g |
| a | 2 | 4 | 5 | t | d |
| b | 1 | 1 | 7 | y | g |
| b | 2 | 2 | 6 | j | d |
| b | 2 | 3 | 4 | u | aa |
| b | 2 | 4 | 7 | i | s |
| c | 1 | 1 | 3 | l | d |
| c | 2 | 2 | 2 | k | o |
| c | 2 | 3 | 8 | n | u |
| c | 3 | 4 | 9 | v | t |
| c | 3 | 5 | 5 | x | e |
| c | 4 | 6 | 8 | w | q |
| c | 4 | 7 | 9 | a | f |
| c | 4 | 8 | 9 | c | g |

**Sheet 2**:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3 |
| a | 2 | 4 |
| b | 1 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 4 |
| c | 1 | 1 |
| c | 2 | 3 |
| c | 3 | 5 |
| c | 4 | 8 |

And here is the expected result: Same data as in **Sheet 2**, but added the columns **Colm 4**...**Colm 6** from **Sheet 1** that match with **Col 1**...**Col 3**:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Colm 4 | Colm 5 | Colm 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3 | 22 | h | g |
| a | 2 | 4 | 5 | t | d |
| b | 1 | 1 | 7 | y | g |
| b | 2 | 4 | 7 | i | s |
| c | 1 | 1 | 3 | l | d |
| c | 2 | 3 | 8 | n | u |
| c | 3 | 5 | 5 | x | e |
| c | 4 | 8 | 9 | c | g |

Here the screenshot wit the sample input and output:
[this is an example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNX1k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula in `O2` cell, then expand to the right:

```
=XLOOKUP($H$2:$H$9&$I$2:$I$9&$J$2:$J$9,
  $A$2:$A$17&$B$2:$B$17&$C$2:$C$17,D2:D17)
```

Alternatively you can use the following formula in the same cell and expand it down:

```
=XLOOKUP(H2&I2&J2,$A$2:$A$17&$B$2:$B$17&$C$2:$C$17,$D$2:$F$17)
```

**Notes:**

- If the first input argument is an array, it can return an array but just for a single column
- You can return multiple columns, but the first input argument needs to be a cell (not a range that expands multiple rows or columns or an array)
- The combination of having as first input argument an array and return more than one column **is not possible**.

Here the output:
[image: sample excel file]

and in `L2`, just the following one:

```
=H2:J9
```